# Laravel models and relations tickets with feedback and users

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to grasp the concept of Eloquent ORM by creating a ticketing system at the moment. What I am trying to achieve is:

- The tickets with the user who posted the ticket
- The feedback belonging to the ticket and the user who entered the
  feedback

**This is what I have right now:**

```
// TicketController.php
    public function index()
    {
        $tickets = Ticket::with('feedback')->with('user')->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->get();

        //dd($tickets);

        return View::make('modules.helpdesk.index')->withTickets($tickets);
    }
```

**And the following models**

```
// Ticket.php
class Ticket extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'helpdesk_tickets';

    public function feedback()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Feedback');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}

// Feedback.php
class Feedback extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'helpdesk_tickets_feedback';

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Ticket');
    }
}

// User.php
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Ticket');
    }
}
```

What I have now is the tickets, their related feedback and user who created the ticket. What I am trying to achieve now is to also get the user who created the feedback.

Comment: 1 What is feedback here? 2  `User belongsTo Ticket` is wrong, should be `hasMany` tickets.

Comment: ticket (question) can have multiple feedback (answers) from multiple users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the relation:

```
// User model
public function tickets()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Ticket'); // adjust namespace if needed
}
```

Next add the relation:

```
// Feedback model
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('User'); // namespace like above
}
```

then use eager loading:

```
// it will execute 4 queries:
// 1st for tickets
// 2nd for feedback
// 3rd for feedbacks' user
// 4th for tickets' user
$tickets = Ticket::with('feedback.user', 'user')->latest()->get();
```

you can then access the relations in a loop, like below:

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
  {{ $ticket->title }} by {{ $ticket->user->name }}
  @foreach ($ticket->feedback as $feedback)
    {{ $feedback->content }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Perfect! Learned a lot from our answer and also conceptwise from the others.

Comment: typo: I meant 'Your answer'

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create nested relations, just like Ticket add a belgonsTo relation on feeback

When you want to use it you can chain relations using the dot notation `feedback.user`

The code

```
// Feedback.php
class Feedback extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'helpdesk_tickets_feedback';

    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Ticket');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belgonsTo('User')
    }
}


 // TicketController.php
public function index()
{
    $tickets = Ticket::with('feedback')->with('user')->with('feedback.user')->orderBy("created_at", "desc")->get();

    //dd($tickets);

    return View::make('modules.helpdesk.index')->withTickets($tickets);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Even though this would work, it will execute more queries than needed. See Jareks answer.

Original Answer:

First of all you need to get your relationships straightened, in User.php you should call the user relationship with HasMany.

```
public function ticket() {
  return $this->hasMany('Ticket');
}
```

In `modules.helpdesk.index` you should now have a Ticket Collection since your attaching the `$ticket` variable to the view.

If you loop through this collection with a foreach loop then what you should get is a model each loop:

```
foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
  // Prints the name property of the Ticket model
  print $ticket->name;

  // Since a ticket only belongs to ONE user then that means that you are trying to fetch a model
  // What we're doing here is getting the User model via the relationship you made in the model Ticket.php and then getting the name.
  print $ticket->user()->first()->username;

  // Since a ticket can have MANY feedbacks that means were fetching a collection 
  // which needs to be broken down to models so we do that looping the collection.
  // Here we are doing the same thing as with the User model except with a collection.
  foreach($ticket->feedback()->get() as $feedback) {
    $feedback->text;
  }
}
```

You should definitely check out the Laravel API and see Collection and Model there. http://laravel.com/api/ You get alot of help from there when you get stuck, trust me :)

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: I had to change Ticket.php to this because it referenced to ticket_id in the user table:

public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

Correct?

Comment: @Klaaz Oh im sorry, I had it backwards. You keep Ticket.php as it is and edit User.php to `public function ticket() { return $this->hasMany('Ticket'); }`. Because One user can have (Has)Many tickets. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is soo wrong. Count queries that will be executed in those loops.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I've never really gotten in to eager loading, but as I see in your answer, that is clearly optimal.

Comment: @jzasnake Yep, it's definitely a must when working with Eloquent.